# How to config Ceph rgw sts key

Tags: ceph, sts

I'm going to use Ceph（rook-ceph V15.2.5）STS service to create temp credentials to access ceph bucket resources by Java, and followed the example steps in: https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/STS/.
When calling the assumeRole to get credentials, it's fialed with 400. And from the rgw log:

```
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700 10 moving my-store.rgw.meta+roles+roles.5c5d7e0e-7492-4b53-8aa2-cd0a316f88af to cache LRU end
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role verifying op params
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role pre-executing
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role executing
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  0 ERROR: Invalid secret key
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role completing
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role op status=-22
debug 2020-12-23T02:57:26.656+0000 7f8fd8dd4700  2 req 451 0.003000119s sts:assume_role http status=400
```

There is a "Invalid secret key" error. Does this means the rgw sts key is invalid?

I have set the config the sts key with 16 chars under rgw pod: /etc/ceph/ceph.conf

```
[client.radosgw.gateway]
rgw sts key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
rgw s3 auth use sts = true
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this issue？Thanks

Comment: Hi @Dylan!
Can you shed some light and describe a way you solved the issue? We are currently suffer from the same problem and have no ideas about a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The section heading [client.radosgw.gateway] is not to be copied blindly from the Ceph docs: there should be a {cluster-name} in there to be replaced. Putting these entries under [global] also works if you have only one cluster or use the same key for all of them.